# Continuity of the integral of a continuous function composed with a measurable one

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and functions $x\in L_1[a,b]$, is it true that the functional

$$ F(x)=\int_a^b g(x(t)) \,d\mu(t) $$

is a continuous function from $L_1[a,b]$ into $\mathbb{R}$? How might I go about showing this?

When $g$ is Lipschitz this is straight forward since the Lipschitz constant of g is the Lipschitz constant for $F$.
$$\Vert F(x)-F(y) \Vert = \Vert  \int_a^b g(x(t))-g(y(t))\,d\mu(t) \Vert$$
$$\leq L_g \int_a^b \Vert x(t)-y(t)\Vert \, d\mu (t)$$
$$=L_g\Vert x-y\Vert_{ L_1[a,b]}$$

...After seeing Dalamar's answer I thought I'd add a counter-example

If $g(x)=x_\varepsilon^2$ and

$$
x_\varepsilon(t)= 
\begin{cases}
   \delta/\varepsilon,& \text{if } a\leq t \leq a+\varepsilon\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

then $\Vert x_\varepsilon-0 \Vert_{L_1([a,b])} =\delta $ for every $\varepsilon$, and 
$$
\Vert F(x)-F(0)\Vert=\int_a^b [x_\varepsilon(t)-0]^2\,d\mu(t) = \int_a^{a+\varepsilon} \frac{\delta^2}{\varepsilon^2}\,d\mu(t)=\frac{\delta^2}{\varepsilon}.
$$

So for $\varepsilon=\delta^2$, 
$$ \Vert x_{\delta^2}-0 \Vert = \delta$$
and
$$\Vert F(x_{\delta^2})-F(0)\Vert =1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's true. For $g(x) = x^2$ your claim would imply $L^1([a,b]) \subset L^2([a,b])$, which does not hold in general. So, for certain continuous functions $g$, $g(x(t))$ won't be in $L^1([a,b])$ and your functional won't be defined.

Comment: Good point. You can add a small perturbation in an L1 sense and get arbitrarily large changes in the integral. Thanks